# Jboss Migration issue while deploying application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss

I am deploying application to JBoss and got below error. its working fine while deploying in weblogic. Any suggestion

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011857: NamingStore is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011857: NamingStore is null
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.<init>(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.<init>(NamingContext.java:125)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Have you able to solve this issue?

Comment: HI @Abhijeet This issue was resolved but i am sorry i am not able to recollect or updated the resolution here.